# Why BS accordion in not working?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is code snippet:

```
<div class="col-sm-4" id="tag-sidebar">
             <div id="accordion">
                 <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a><br>
                  <div id="collapse1" class=" collapse">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor .</div>
                 <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 1</a><br>
                  <div id="collapse2" class=" collapse ">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut aliqui.</div>
            </div>


            <div id="tags-accordion">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#tags-accordion" href="#ta_collapse1">Iesaukumi</a><br>
                <div id="#ta_collapse1" class="collapse">
                    <?php foreach ($iesaukumi as $iesaukums): ?>
                        <a href="#" class="tag" data-value="1_<?php echo $iesaukums['id']; ?>"><?php echo $iesaukums['name']; ?></a>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and the weird thing that I have been trying to understand for hours is that data-parent "accordion" is working while data-parent "tags-accordion" is not working.

"tags-accordion" is a copy+paste. I have checked without php part still the same. First accordion works but second does not collapse.

I am sure that there is some small stupid mistake however I have spend hour finding it with no success. I re-wrote the code but still the some. I am angry with this code! Pleasr help me understand the issue

**UPDATE**

```
<div id="tags-accordion">

                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#tags-accordion" href="#tacollapse1">Iesaukumi</a><br>
                <div id="#tacollapse1" class="collapse">
                    <?php foreach ($iesaukumi as $iesaukums): ?>
                        <a href="#" class="tag" data-value="1_<?php echo $iesaukums['id']; ?>"><?php echo $iesaukums['name']; ?></a>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
                <?php $prevGroup = null;?>
                <?php foreach ($tags as $row): ?>
                    <?php if($prevGroup != $row['grupa']):?>
                        <?php if(!is_null($prevGroup)):?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif;?>
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#tags-accordion" href="#tacollapse<?php echo $row['grupa'];?>"><?php echo $row['grupa'];?></a><br>
                        <div id="#tacollapse<?php echo $row['grupa'];?>" class="collapse">
                        <?php $prevGroup = $row['grupa'];?>
                    <?php endif;?>
                    <a href="#" class="tag" data-value="2_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></a>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: you are end tag-accordain here  <?php if(!is_null($prevGroup)):?>
                            </div>

Comment: Close previous group and open new group

Answer (score -1):

check this..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 
 <div class="col-sm-4" id="tag-sidebar">
 <p> part 1</p>
             <div id="accordion">
                 <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a><br>
                 <div id="collapse1" class=" collapse">Lorem ipsum dolor .</div>
                 
                 <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a><br>
                 <div id="collapse2" class=" collapse ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut aliqui.</div>
                  
                 <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#Iesaukumi1">Collapsible Group 2</a><br>
                 <div id="Iesaukumi1" class=" collapse ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut aliqui.</div>
                    
                 
            </div>

   <p>part 2 </p>
            <div id="tags-accordion">
             
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#tags-accordion" href="#Iesaukumi">PHP Iesaukumi 1</a><br>
                <div id="Iesaukumi" class="collapse">PHP Code.</div>
                
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#tags-accordion" href="#collapse22">PHP Group 1</a><br>
                <div id="collapse22" class="collapse">PHP Code.</div>
               
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to avoid panel formating. I have found answer on fixing issues when not using panel class but given problems in not about that. The first accordion work even without panel class...

Comment: Yes Just try the same with different ids. Updated the answer.

Comment: So your example is working(same as my first accordion) but I can not undestand where is the difference? The problem is that I have much more complex php code later on so I can not copy+paste solution straight away. I will update my question

Comment: @KārlisJanisels Sorry I don't know php. Just tried to help you on accordian part. Still You can replace paste and try your php code in this accordain. and if it works thats fine. Else you need to check with the php code